# How to configure package.json to add a "self compiled binary" as a dependency?

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I am very new to the concept of npm-install. Please throw some insights into where I might be going wrong. I have a .js file through which I am supposed to invoke a binary with some command line arguments.I did write package.json setting the main parameter to the javascript file and I am using preinstall script that compiles the code and creates a binary that is supposed to be used by my java script file.

Couple of questions:

1. How do I make package.json take this compiled binary as dependency for the js file?
2. npm install runs fine for me but I do not see any output folder whatsoever. I was hoping it would generate a .node_module in pwd and copy the contents onto bin/ folder in that. May be, I am missing something.

   ```
   npm info prepublish test@0v.0.1
   npm verb from cache <pwd>/package.json
   npm verb readInstalled returning test@0.0.1
   npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
   npm info ok
   ```

Can someone please through some insights into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to handle it. Using a js module and using my node as required in that module causes npm to setup my node in node_modules/ folder. I used a pre-install shell script to compile my binary and used the relative path to use the binary upon execution.

Thanks for all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include your binary file in `package.json`. If you're using `Express`, put it in the node-modules folder within the parent directory. Otherwise, you can either specify the whole path to the file where you call it or put the file in the parent directory. For global installations, the node-modules folder is usually created at: `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu, I tried looking for node_modules in home folder in .npm/ directory, but I don't seem to find it. I also looked for node_module/ inside of parent directory where "npm install" was triggered and that  too is not present.

Comment: does [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/npm-folders.1.html) help?